# What does [converted] mean at the bottom of vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I have a log file, and when I open it via vim, it looks not readable, and it has [converted] at the bottom.  What does [converted] mean?

Is there a way to fix the format issue so that it is human readable?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a log file is humanly readable. At least some of the files in `/var/log/` are not. Which program did make the log file? What is its file name?

Comment: @Anthon The original log looks good, but after the log rotation by daemontools, it is no longer human readable.

Comment: Did it get compressed by the rotation. Did you run the `file` command on the file?

Comment: @Anthon The file type is `data`.  What does that mean?

Comment: Essentially that the file command does not recognize the type with further accuracy, or that entries are missing in the `magic` rules.

Comment: I figured out the solution. The log file was zipped, so I need to use `zless` to view it.

Comment: I find it kind of strange your `file` command dit not recognise a zip file. Which version are you running?

Comment: After I run `:set fileencoding=utf-8`, `file` outputs `data`.  When I run `file` against the original log file, it outputs `gzip compressed data, from Unix`.  Thus, the proper solution is to run `file` first instead of run `:set`, which further messes up the file.

Comment: Mingy, I was referring to the commandline command `file` not some command run from within `vi`. I think that is why you got data and not some more informative description.

Comment: What I meant was changing file encoding corrupt the file, so that the `file` command no longer works as expected.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It means that `vim` detected that the file did not match the charset given by your locale and made a conversion. If you run the command `:set` from within `vim`:

```
:set
--- Options ---
  autoindent          fileformat=dos      scroll=7            textwidth=70
  background=dark     filetype=asciidoc   shiftwidth=2        ttyfast
  cscopetag           helplang=en         softtabstop=2       ttymouse=sgr
  cscopeverbose       hlsearch            syntax=asciidoc
noendofline           list                tabpagemax=3
  expandtab           ruler               textmode
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  comments=s1:/*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,fb:-,fb:*,fb:+,fb:.,fb:>
  cscopeprg=/usr/bin/cscope
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
```

Notice the last 2 options, `fileencoding` & `fileencodings`.

The first is the encoding used for the current file, the second is a comma
separated list of recognized encodings.

So when you see that message `vim` is telling you that it's completed converting the file from `fileencoding` to `encoding`.

Check out `:help fileencoding` or `:help encoding` for additional details.

#### Reference

I found the thread below, which I used as a source when this was answered. The original site is now gone (accessible in this answer's history), so I'm moving the contents of that thread here for posterity sake. The [link was still in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130217064626/http://us.generation-nt.com/vim-question-what-means-converted-help-172107471.html).

```
#1 Eli the Bearded January 21st, 2004 - 06:51 pm ET | Report spam
In comp.os.linux.misc, Leon. wrote:
Hide the quote
"Gaétan Martineau" wrote in message
news:E9jLb.2903$
> [ system_notes]$ vi installation_chouette.txt
> What means the [converted] at the bottom of the screen, as in:
> "installation_chouette.txt" [converted] 2576L, 113642C

It means that vim detected that the file did not match the
charset given by your locale and made a conversion. What does

:set

Tell you about "fileencoding" and "fileencodings"? The first is
the encoding used for the current file, the second is a comma
separated list of recognized encodings.

Hide the quote
> This file has accented characters. How can I save the file so that if I
> reload if again, I do not see "converted"?



Figure out what charset you want, and then

:set fileencoding=[charset]
:w

Hide the quote
It means deleting the Microsoft Dos/ Windows CR LF end of lines, to just
LF - unix standard end of lines.

It does not. If you open a file with DOS line ends, vim reports [dos]
after the filename, not [converted]. If you do have a dos file that
you wish to convert to unix line ends, you can

:set fileformat=unix
:w

Elijah
```

Answer (score 16):

In `vim` command mode, type:

```
:help read-messages
```

You can see:

```
[converted]      conversion from 'fileencoding' to
                 'encoding' done
```

In general, it means that vim detected the file did not match the 
charset given by your locale and made a conversion.

To see more details, try `:help fileencoding`, `:help fileencodings`.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the file-on-disk does not use the same charset as Vim's memory area, and that the conversion from one to the other was successful. Press escape key and type this command.

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

Save the file and try reading again.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do a good job of explaining the meaning, but here's how to fix it programmatically.

### The Fix

Determine the file encoding using `file` and then convert using `iconv`.

```
$ iconv -f $(file -b --mime-encoding my_file) -t utf-8 my_file > my_file_converted
```

### The Explanation

- `iconv -f` sets the encoding you want to encode "from"
- `file -b --mime-encoding my_file` outputs the encoding of the current file, such as `iso-8859-1`
- `-t utf-8` sets the encoding you want to encode "to"
- `my_file > my_file_converted` writes the converted data to a file; `iconv` writes to stdout by default.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805418/how-can-i-find-encoding-of-a-file-via-a-script-on-linux